# Open Options menu on click event of icon in ag-grid in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, onclick

I have an icon inside ag-grid cell and on the click of icon I am trying to open a popup near the icon which will have edit and delete as below:

[image]

I have code as below:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  style="padding-top: 10px;" 
  [rowData]="rowData" 
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  [pagination]="true" 
  [paginationPageSize]="5"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"  
  domLayout="autoHeight" 
>
</ag-grid-angular>

public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [{
{
          headerName: 'Options',
          field: 'propId',
          cellRenderer: function (params: any) {
            let propId = params.value;
            const eDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var optionsOnHtml = '<i class="icon-options" style="color:#0672CB; margin-right: 10px;padding-right:10px" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
            eDiv.innerHTML = optionsOnHtml;
            
            const optionsIcon = eDiv.querySelectorAll('.icon-options')[0];
            
            optionsIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
              // Code here
            });
            return eDiv;
          },
          cellStyle: {
            borderRightColor: '#e1e1e1',
            borderRightWidth: '1px',
            borderRightStyle: 'solid',
          },
        },];
```

I wanted to know how can I add these two options along with propId so that I can edit / delete the record with propId.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add getContextMenuItems in your ag-grid-angular.

```
<ag-grid-angular
..
[getContextMenuItems]="getContextMenuItems"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

Then add something like:

```
getContextMenuItems(params) {
    let result = [
        {
          name: "Edit",
          action: () => { this.openEdit(params) }
        },
        {
          name: "Delete",
          action: () => { this.openDelete(params) }
        }
      ];
    });
    return result;
  }
```

And then finally bind this where you are initializing the grid.

```
 this.getContextMenuItems = this.getContextMenuItems.bind(this);
```

This [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/context-menu/) should help